# Pass JSON variable as a parameter in the Snowflake javascript stored procedure

Tags: json, stored-procedures, parameters, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored proc where I construct the JSON with the values and I want to pass this in to child procs and update the same JSOn variable and return it back.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROC1()
RETURNS STRING 
LANGUAGE JavaScript

AS
'

--Some functions and constants 

  function execSqlSingleValue(sql_text){
    exec_result = snowflake.execute({sqlText:sql_text});
    exec_result.next();
    return exec_result.getColumnValue(1);
  }

  const column1 = `ABC`;
  const column2 = `DEF`;
  const column3 = `GHL`;

  var v1_json = {
    col1: column1,
    col2: column2,
    col3: column3,
    col4: `NONE`,
    col5: 0,

  }

try{
  return execSqlSingleValue(`CALL PROC2(\'${v1_json}\')`);
  }

  catch(err){
    return JSON.stringify(v1_json);
  }
'
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC2(v1_json VARIANT)

RETURNS STRING 
LANGUAGE JavaScript

AS
'
```

const column4 = `XYZ`;  -- Some other calculation
const column5 = `MMM`;  -- Some other calculation

```
v1_json.col4 = `${column4}`;
v1_json.col5 = `${column5}`;

return JSON.stringify(v1_json);

'
;
```

I have tried to do it with VARIANT and VARCHAR , but could not succeed.How do we achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to convert it to a string and then convert JSON in the child procedure?

```
snowflake.execute(
            {
            sqlText: "call PROC2(?);",
            binds:[ JSON.stringify(v1_json) ]
            }
```

In the child procedure (v1_json is defined as a varchar parameter):

```
var json_obj = JSON.parse(v1_json)
```

Comment: Thanks Gokhan, But I was looking to not bind , can we pass directly like i mentioned in the example ? I have defined it as VARIANT in the child proc .